# How can I get an item from a generic list based on two conditions?

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, generic-list

I have a generic list of a custom type, of which I'm trying to get back one type instance. I've tried both "FirstOrDefault" and "Where" using the two conditions which need to be true, but both of them give me the same err msg ("Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'lambda expression' and 'lambda expression'")

Here they are:

```
// FirstOrDefault
UnitItemCodeItemID uicii = 
    unitItemCodeItemIDList
        .FirstOrDefault((u => u.Unit == _unit) && (d => d.Description == desc));


// Where
UnitItemCodeItemID uicii = 
    unitItemCodeItemIDList
        .Where((u => u.Unit == _unit) && (d => d.Description == desc));
```

I don't know if it's pertinent, but the class is:

```
public class UnitItemCodeItemID
{
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The `&&` goes inside the lambda: `.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Unit == _unit && u.Description == desc);`

Comment: @DavidG Try to avoid posting answers in comments. Even if it's a one-liner, an answer is an answer! :-)

Comment: @GediminasMasaitis I know what I'm doing, I've been around here quite a while (check my rep...) but I don't think this question is worthy of a full answer.

Comment: @GediminasMasaitis - Yes, I agree with DavidG - it's perfectly fine to provide a simple answer as a comment to the question.

Comment: @DavidG I tend to agree, especially when this question could arguably be closed because of a typographical error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to provide just ONE lambda:

```
UnitItemCodeItemID uicii = unitItemCodeItemIDList
    .FirstOrDefault(obj => obj.Unit == _unit && obj.Description == desc);
```

Think about it this way: it's exactly like writing a foreach loop in a function. Like so:

```
public UnitItemCodeItemID ExtractFirst(IEnumerable<UnitItemCodeItemID> unitItemCodeItemIDList)
{
    foreach(var obj in unitItemCodeItemIDList)
    {
        if (obj.Unit == _unit && obj.Description == desc)
            return obj;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Your lamba must provide the "if" part, the rest is in the Linq implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a single lambda expression that encapsulates both conditions

```
.Where(p => p.Unit == _unit && p.Description == desc);
```

Your previous attempt was trying to combine two separate lambda expressions with an `and` statement.